How to open a folder/file in VSCode in Chromebook Linux via right click and then opening it, the same way it can be done on Windows on right click?
I'm trying to open a folder in VSCode (linux app - stable channel - debian linux) via right click on my chromebook but the options menu appearing on right click does not provide an option to open the folder in VSCode.
This started happening quite recently, I'm not sure but could be due to ChromeOS update which did some changing in linux apps accessing and opening the folders in linux apps or something similar to that.
For Folder
Example of menu appearing on right click in Files app in ChromeOS missing the to open with - vscode option
For File
Example of menu appearing on right click in Files app in ChromeOS missing the to open with - vscode option
Although, I am able to open folders and files with other linux apps as I tried to open up an image in image editing linux app.
I have tried to open the folder in terminal, by typing code after providing the path of the folder. I have also tried to open folder from within the VSCode itself by going to File > Open Folder... menu, and then selecting a folder. All of this worked but it is not as convenient and handy as the right click is when it comes down to opening files and folder conveniently. I tried to reinstall VSCode as well but no luck with that too.
I have also checked that if the VSCode installed on my chromebook is up-to-date or not. It is on latest version but still the problem presists...
Kindly please give your input if you know anything in this regard. Do I need to change a setting in VSCode app or something else or it is because of the chromebook recent update? Right know, I'm on chromeOS stable channel --- Version 125.0.6422.140 (Official Build) (64-bit)
